# Override Wizard in Odoo to change text fields

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-14

I'm trying yo change the paragraphs from a OOTB form for a model we are inheriting but it has proven to be quite challenging to modify OOTB elements can this be achieved??
I'm in the Expenses Module from Odoo btw and the view im trying to change is a wizard that gets executed by a button.

[image]

Comment: What is the challenge here? Did you find the right view or are you struggling to find it? Or do you think you've done it already, but it's not working? If so please add your view extension (XML) in your question. Thanks

Comment: Thank you, yes i was having problems inheriting the correct id to modifying it with xpath but i manage to do it.

Comment: Ah okay, the "bug" hint on the answer should have helped you then ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Please check the code and modify it according to your need. Also in order to get ID for the records which you want to inherit you can simply click the bug icon which is showing in your screenshot.

```
<record id="view_id_inh" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">model.name.form</field>
        <field name="model">model.name</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="module.view_id"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//p" position="replace">
                <p></p>
            </xpath>
            </field>
        </record>
```